# Problem installing bitbucket.org/ww/goautoneg for Stellar go using dep ensure -v

Tags: go-sdk

I'm considering contributing to https://github.com/stellar/go and have pulled the repo and am trying to install dependencies using `dep ensure -v`

Checking I see It looks like mercurial is a dependency for goautoneg see [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-openstack/issues/203)
so I installed mercurial on my mac 

`brew install mercurial
brew upgrade mercurial`

but the issue remains - any help is appreciated.

Log is [here](https://gist.github.com/johnwhitton/1d3f5c433d89b5052c3d61864bc18556)

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved, I'm unsure whether this was just a timing issue (where I needed to be more patient) or if I needed to install mercurial.
Steps I used for resolution

`brew install mercurial
brew update mercurial
go get bitbucket.org/ww/goautoneg
git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/"
dep ensure -v`

After 10 minutes dep ensure completed succesfully.

**Additional Information**

I found the build documentation for Horizon [here](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/reference/admin.md#Building) am reviewing this now, but it clearly mentions the mecurial dependency.

Comment: Also I just found this documentation https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/reference/admin.md#Building which I'll review.

Comment: if you would accept your own answer, that would be awesome :)